# Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' in inner join

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, url

I got error

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and
> (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
>
> near (inner join `cb_receipt` on `cb_receipt`.`code` =
> `upload_transaksi`.`code`)

how to fix it?

```
select `upload_transaksi`.`id` from `giisystem_gim`.`upload_transaksi_images` 
inner join `upload_transaksi` on `upload_transaksi`.`id` = `upload_transaksi_images`.`upload_transaksi_id` 
inner join `cb_receipt` on `cb_receipt`.`code` = `upload_transaksi`.`code` 
where `cb_receipt`.`id` = 23355
```

Comment: Specify needed collation explicitly. For example, `.. on cb_receipt.code = upload_transaksi.code COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ..`.

Comment: `SELECT `upload_transaksi`.`id` 
FROM `giisystem_gim`.`upload_transaksi_images` 
INNER JOIN `upload_transaksi` ON `upload_transaksi`.`id` = `upload_transaksi_images`.`upload_transaksi_id` 
INNER JOIN `cb_receipt` ON `cb_receipt`.`code` COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci = `upload_transaksi`.`code` COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
WHERE `cb_receipt`.`id` = 23355;`